# Add consistency in access to the reputation leagues from per-site-metas

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, reputation-leagues

The new display of your position in the leagues in your profile page is [also shown on the per-site-meta of the other sites](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer). It is, of course, a mirror of the same value (and link) as the main Q&A site.

I don't particularly mind it, but back when the leagues were first introduced, a bug report led to [the removal of the link to the reputation leagues from the Users page](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users). This wasn't restored in the new version, so it seems intentional to keep it removed.

It's a minor thing, but I think it would be nice to match the accessibility. Either the display on the profile page should be removed, or the users page should have the link returned. I actually kinda prefer the former, to de-emphasize competition inside the Meta discussion, but the latter also works.